# Is Python's Counter a hash map?

Tags: python, time-complexity, counter

The title is pretty much the question. Is Python's build-in Counter a hash map? Does get() and put() from a Counter have O(1) time complexity?

Comment: Yes, it's a dict subclass.

Comment: Yes, it is a `dict`

Answer (score 1):

The Python documentation is extremely useful. I highly recommend getting comfortable checking there first for any questions you have.

The first sentence in the [collection.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) docs:

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects.